# How to delete the other Windows Operating System when I have two

Tags: windows-7

I have two Windows 7, one in drive C and other in drive D. I use the one in drive D. I want to remove the one present in drive C, to find more free disk space.

But I cannot delete the Windows folder present in drive C. It says you need permission something. Also when my computer starts it asks me which OS I want to use, the two OS names are the same "Windows 7". I chose the upper one, this is the one present in Drive D. However when  I choose the other one that does not run, computer restarts after sometime before logging in. This is because I have deleted everything associated with the previous Windows, except the Windows folder. Because I can not delete it.

How can I delete this Windows folder present in drive C, which I cannot use ( and I don't want to use). Please tell me the simple way, ASAP.

Comment: You need to take ownership of the second partition, and then change your boot loader to remove the second instance of Windows.

Comment: Are C: and D: different volumes on the same physical drive, or two separate physical drives?  I'm just guessing, since you didn't mention  any boot managers, C: is probably the boot drive containing the active partition.  If this is two physical drives, and not just two volumes on one drive, you could make D: a boot disk, and its volume "active", such that the system boots to the installation you wish to keep.  Then you should be able to format the undesired installation (the old "C:" volume), clobbering all the files.  Copy any desired files from the old C: to D: before doing so.

Comment: @ Randolph West , I have changed the ownership of C:\Windows folder and its contents to the user account that I use, now i think I can delete this folder and its contents, But I have a doubt that, if I delete these files, would there by any problem starting the windows 7 that I have installed in Drive D ? And is this necessary to change the boot loader to remove the second instance of Windows, actually I dont know how to do that. Please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About dirty Windows folder:**

a) Simplest way:
Browse C:\Windows, hit the F3, search for everything. When searching complete, select all items and delete them, skip protected items. Then move C:\Windows under the carpet. Now you freed the space. If you really want to delete the remained files; take their ownership, then delete them again.

b) If you have Windows 7 Install disk, boot the PC from install DVD. Format the drive C:, go back and repair your Windows 7 -because probably it won't boot. Or it will.

c) Boot form Windows 7 Install disk. Open a command prompt. Type del c:\windows /s  or Format c:

P.S: If you don't have the DVD, Win 7 has embedded recovery tools, just turn the power down, next boot, it will ask for recovery.

**About boot menu:**

Right click My Computer > choose Properties. At the left side click Advanced System Settings link. Select Advanced tab. There is a Startup & Recovery button. You can choose the default OS and menu duration. If you set 0 as duration, menu won't appear next time. If you want to totally rip the older OS menu item, there are a few tools that modify startup menu.

Comment: how to take the ownership of the remaining files ? I want to delete them, they are worth 10 GB of space.

Comment: hey I have changed ownership of C:\Windows folder and its contents to the user account that I use, now i think I can delete this folder and its contents, But I have a doubt that, if I delete these files, would there by any problem starting the windows 7 that I have installed in Drive D ?

Comment: You can feel free delete C.\windows + c:\users + c:\programs with their subfolders.

Comment: Hey I tried deleting them but I can't. Only 1 GB is deleted and remaining 9 GB left, what is the problem now ?

Comment: I can't delete the windows folder and its contents even when I have changed the ownership of those files. Can anyone help ?

Comment: You need to set permissions. Now you are owner of c:\windows and you can modify the permissions.

Comment: ok, let me try :)

Comment: I have changed permissions (full control to my user), still I cannot delete the windows folder. Every time I try to delete is says deleting 729MB, but the folder is worth 9 GB, and when I check back nothing has been deleted, not even 729 MB. What is the problem ?

Comment: Just delete c:\windows. If you can it's ok. Remove all permissions then add Everyone with full permissions.

Comment: hey Can I simply format drive C ?

Comment: @NimeCloud let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1149/discussion-between-shanky-and-nime-cloud)

Comment: hey I have deleted everything in Local Disk C, but when I check in its  properties, there is still 4.29 GB of used space. Why is that ?

Comment: RecycleBin or System Volume Information?  Try to show all files including hidden & system.